# Can't center h1 inside main tags

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to center my H1 tag inside my main tags. If I use position fixed with top:50% and left:50%, it works a bit, though I am never able to center it to the middle. Nothing else will work. Any advice ?

```css
main .container {
  margin-top: 40%; }
  main .container .row h1 {
    text-align: center !important; }
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>WELCOME</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Could other elements like a navbar or html interefere with this ? I also have this property for my html:

```html
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)),
  url("/static/images/background.png") no-repeat fixed center center;
}
```

For me it's rendered like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyz8L.jpg

Comment: May I suggest looking into flexbox rather than `margin-top:50%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```css
.centered-div {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row centered-div">
            <h1>WELCOME</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following, hope this helps:

```css
main {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>WELCOME</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also specify a height value for the container.

For example;

```css
main .container {
  margin-top: 45%;
  height: 10%;
  margin-bottom:45% }
  main .container .row h1 {
    text-align: center !important; }
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>WELCOME</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

should work as you desire. You can change the % values accordingly to change the position of the text better. Just be careful to make them 100% in total.

Edit: Sergio's answer is better though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
html, body, main, .container, .row{
  height:100%;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1>WELCOME</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```